# a regular curve with $\kappa(t)>0$ is helix if and only if $\frac{\kappa}{\tau}$ is constant

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, frenet-frame

> A curve is said to be helix if its tangent line have a constant angle with a fixed direction. i.e. $\langle T(t),u\rangle$ is constant for some unit vector $u$.

I am trying to prove: a regular curve with $\kappa(t)>0$ is helix if and only if $\frac{\kappa}{\tau}$ is constant.

I can show the sufficient part： if $\alpha(t)$ is helix, then
$\langle T'\!, u\rangle=0$
and therefore $\langle N,u\rangle=0$, which implies
$\langle-\kappa(t)T(t)+\tau(t)B(t), u\rangle=0$. We then have
$$
\frac{\kappa(t)}{\tau(t)} 
= \frac{\langle T(t),u\rangle}{\langle B(t),u\rangle},
$$
which is constant, since
$\langle T(t),u\rangle,\langle B(t),u\rangle$ are constant.

But I have no idea in proving the reverse direction.

Comment: For the second part of the theorem see the book "Differential geometry" by Martin M. Lipschutz, chapter 4 – curvature and torsion 4.21.

Comment: You can reverse your argument. which step doesn't work?

Comment: @Mars it seems that we have to find some constant vector $u$